# PHP stops responding

Tags: php, mysql, intellij-idea

I have a small(100-ish rows, 5 columns) table which is displayed in full for a control panel feature. When using IntelliJ to test development, it responds to the initial request, but never completes executing, and thus never serves any content. If I deploy the PHP files to my local web server, it serves the same content with no hesitation at all. Sometimes, when I load parts of the control panel that use no database access, it loads it just fine(albeit slow). I've upped the max memory allowed for requests in my cli/php.ini, and also increased the memory available to IntelliJ. My idea64.vmoptions is as follows:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx3G
-XX:MaxPermSize=750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

If I dump the table, it loads the page again, so I assume the problem is related to how much memory IntelliJ allows php to use, but I'm quite stumped as to what to look for. The only special thing about the table, as far as I know, is that it uses a very large primary key column. Table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
`url`        VARCHAR(767)               NOT NULL,
`link_group` INT(10) UNSIGNED           NOT NULL,
`isActive`   TINYINT(1)                 NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`hammer`     TINYINT(1)                 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`url`),
KEY `group` (`link_group`)
)
ENGINE =InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8mb4,
ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;
```

The row format is compressed to allow for said large primary keys. How should I proceed to if not solve it, find the cause?

I tried following Peter's suggestions, to no avail. I'm beginning to think this may just be IntelliJ not properly being able to serve PHP in my case. New table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`url` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
`link_group` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`hammer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
KEY `group` (`link_group`),
FULLTEXT KEY `url_2` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Just to be clear, the MySQL performance doesn't seem bad. SELECT * FROM links executes in 0.0005 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to recreate that table. Your table definition might be causing the unpredicatable behaviour.

Try using the `TEXT` data type for the `url` field. Also, using that as a PRIMARY key is not funny. Use an `id` field for the primary key and then, add a `unique index` to the `url` field (if so desired).

Comment: Why do you recommend `TEXT`? VARCHAR seems appropriate to me.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? There might be a size limit to the VARCHAR data type that I don't really understand because it depends on the value length of the row. You need to read this page: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html] (for mysql 5.0. change your version from the left link sidebar.

Comment: Even at 4 Bytes per character (he's using utf8mb4, indicating a new MySQL version) the row size may be  a bit larger than 3000 Bytes, but the row size maximum is 65,535 Bytes just the same as the maximum length for VARCHAR (since MySQL 5.0.3), see [The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) Older MySQL will allow only 255 as maximum length, but shouldn't be in use anymore. Especially not in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the table structure, but this didn't help. I'm keeping the new structure as suggested due to it probably being way smarter in terms of indexing.

Comment: I'm having the feeling that this is IntelliJ's bug.